# Replace exit code based on stdout?

Tags: bash

I've got a command I want to do some scripting around, but it returns a non-zero exit code for a scenario I don't care about. This scenario is detectable based on the stdout response, so I want to "correct" the status code so I can do some scripting around it.

e.g.

```sh
$ hg evolve
nothing to evolve on current working copy parent
(6 other orphan in the repository, do you want --any or --rev)
$ echo $?
2
```

Is there some convenient way I can wrap this with pure bash so I can change the status code IFF stdout matches some regex?

e.g.

```
fixstatus '^nothing to evolve\b' -- hg evolve # would return 0 if stdout from hg evolve matches that regex, otherwise returns whatever it would have normally returned
```

Something like that. I don't think I can solve it with piping because then the exit code would match that final command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
output=$( hg evolve )
status=$?
if echo "$output" | grep -q '^nothing to evolve\b'; then
    status=0
fi
sh -c "exit $status"  # Set $?
```

So, in a function, that could look like:

```
fixstatus() {
    local output status regex
    regex="$1"
    shift
    output=$( "$@" )
    status=$?
    if echo "$output" | grep -q -- "$regex"; then
        status=0
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$output"
    return $status
}
```

And call it like: `fixstatus '^nothing to evolve\b' hg evolve`

Since you're using bash, you could also use `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` rather than `grep`.

Comment: BTW in case of bash, the echo+pipe involved in the command `echo "$output" | grep …` can be avoided using a [here-string](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html): `grep … <<< "$output"`

Answer (score 1):

In the interpreter itself as much as possible:

```
output="$( hg evolve )"
status=$?
case "$output" in
"nothing to evolve"*) status=0;;
esac
exit $status
```

Technically that doesn't *exactly* match the regex you used, so here's an alternate:

```
output="$( hg evolve )"
status=$?
pat='^nothing to evolve\b'
if [[ "$output" =~ $pat ]] # $pat not quoted
then status=0
fi
exit $status
```

Comment: This is less portable, but OP specified `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `hg` was writing to stderr. Tweaked [William's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729819/65387) a bit, now it seems to work for my use-case:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex="$1"
shift
{ output=$("$@" 2>&1 >&3 3>&-); } 3>&1
status=$?
if \grep -q --perl-regexp -- "$regex" <<<"$output"; then
    exit 0
fi
exit $status
```

I put that in `~/bin/errstatus0` so other scripts can run it (alias doesn't work), and created an alias in `~/.hgrc`:

```
_evolve = !errstatus0 '^nothing to evolve\b' hg evolve --all --no-update
```

Now `hg _evolve` return the status I want and I can chain it with `&&`.